# Python class methods to construct child classes

Tags: python, inheritance, factory

I don't know how to cleanly reuse the classmethod of a derived class in python to construct the child class:

```
class Base:
     def __init__(... lots of parameters .... )
         ... assign parameters .... 
         
     @classmethod
     def from_file(cls,file)
         .... read lots of parameters ....
         return cls(.... lots of parameters .... )

class Derived(Base):
     def __init__(derived_param, .... base parameters ..... )
         super().__init__(base parameters)

     @classmethod
     def from_file(cls,file)
         ??? do i have to replicate the whole code from   
         Base.from_file() here ????
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to redefine a method in a child class. By default, it uses the parent function:

```py
class Base:
     def __init__(... lots of parameters .... )
         ... assign parameters .... 
         
     @classmethod
     def from_file(cls,file)
         .... read lots of parameters ....
         return cls(.... lots of parameters .... )

class Derived(Base):
     def __init__(derived_param, .... base parameters ..... )
         super().__init__(base parameters)

derived_class = Derived(...params...)
derived_class.from_file(...params...)  # This line will work without any further changes
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this may be only 50% of the answer. What I need is a from_file classmethod of the Derived class. In this class I cannot call ```Base.from_file()``` because the derived class does not exist yet. What is worse, at some point  i need to call cls(derived_param, base param) where cls == Derived and I dont have the base param. The workaround seems to be to actually call Base.from_file() in the Derived.from_file() method and pass the parameters.

Comment: Gotcha. You could use `super().from_file` for that

Comment: Not the parent class, but whatever class actually *invokes* the class method, regardless of which class *defined* the method. `d = Derived.from_file(...)` will create an instance of `Derived`, even though the method is inherited from `Base`.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround seems to be to actually call Base.from_file() in the Derived.from_file() method and pass the parameters.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self,base_var):
        self.base_var = base_var

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls):
        """ read from file here"""
        base_init = "base_init"
        return cls(base_var=base_init)


class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self,derived_var,base_var):
        super().__init__(base_var)
        self.derived_var = derived_var

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls):
        derived_init = "derived_init"
        base = Base.from_file()
        derived = cls(derived_init,base.base_var)

        return derived
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is now the fancy answer:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, **params):
        self.assign(params,['base_x','base_y'])

    def assign(self,params,required):
        for k in required:
            # will throw an exception if a required variable is not present
            self.__dict__[k] = params[k]


    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls):
        """ read from file here"""
        return cls(base_x='xval',base_y='yval')


class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, **params):
        super().__init__(**params) # it does not hurt to have all the derived params in the dict
        self.assign(params,['derived_var']) # here we assign only the derived vars, note this has to be a list

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls):
        base = Base.from_file()
        derived_dict = { 'derived_var' : 'derived value'}
        derived = cls( **(derived_dict | base.__dict__) )
        return derived


if __name__ == '__main__':
    derived = Derived.from_file()
    print("Base: ", derived.base_x, derived.base_y," Derived: ", derived.derived_var)
```

with this you have only to specify the required attributes in each child class and a key error will be thrown if you miss one.

Answer (score 0):

Class methods receive the class that *invokes* the method as the first argument.

If you write

```
d = Derived.from_file(3)
```

then it's the `from_file` function defined in `Base` that gets called, but with `Derived`, not `Base`, as the first argument (which gets bound to `cls`). As a result, you'll get an instance of the correct class back.

However, if you need to do `Derived`-specific things using the file, you'll still need to override the method and use `super()` to do any `Base`-specific things before your own `Derived`-specific things.

```
class Base:
     def __init__(*, x, y, z, **kwargs)
         super().__init__(**kwargs)
         # assign x, y, z
         
     @classmethod
     def from_file(cls, file)
         # Process file to get values for x, y, and z
         return cls(x=..., y=..., z=...)

class Derived(Base):
     def __init__(*, a, b, c, **kwargs )
         super().__init__(**kwargs)
         # assign a, b, c

     @classmethod
     def from_file(cls, file)
         obj = super().from_file(file)
         # Do additional work with obj
         return obj
```